# Vector Shape Difference & intersection

Tags: vector-graphics

Let me explain my problem:

I have a black vector shape (let's say it's a series of joined, straight lines for now, but it'd be nice if I could also support quadratic curves).

I also have a rectangle of a predefined width and height.  I'm going to place it on top of the black shape, and then take the union of the two.

My first issue is that I don't know how to quickly extract vector unions, but I think there is a well-defined formula I can figure out for myself.

My second, and more tricky issue is how to efficiently detect the position the rectangle needs to be in (i.e., what translation and rotation are needed by the matrices), in order to maximize the black, remaining after the union (see figure, below).

The red outlined shape below is ~33% black; the green is something like 85%; and there are positions for this shape & rectangle wherein either could have 100% coverage.

[image: optimal rectangle positioning]

Obviously, I can brute-force this by trying every translation and rotation value for every point where at least part of the rectangle is touching the black shape, then keep track of the one with the most black coverage.  The problem is, I can only try a finite number of positions (and may therefore miss the maximum).  Apart from that, it feels very inefficient!

Can you think of a more efficient way of tackling this problem?

Something from my Uni days tells me that a Fourier transform might improve the efficiency here, but I can't figure out how I'd do that with a vector shape!

Answer (score 2):

Three ideas that have promise of being faster and/or more precise than brute force search:

1. Suppose you have a 3d physics engine.  Define a "cone-shaped" surface where the apex is at say (0,0,-1), the black polygon boundary on the z=0 plane with its centroid at the origin, and the cone surface is formed by connecting the apex with semi-infinite rays through the polygon boundary.  Think of a party hat turned upside down and crumpled to the shape of the black polygon. Now constrain the rectangle to be parallel to the z=0 plane and initially so high above the cone (large z value) that it's easy to find a place where it's definitely "inside".  Then let the rectangle fall downward under gravity, twisting about z and translating in x-y only as it touches the cone, staying inside all the way down until it settles and can't move any farther.  The collision detection and force resolution of the physics engine takes care of the complexities.  When it settles, it will be in a position of maximal coverage of the black polygon in a local sense.  (If it settles with z<0, then coverage is 100%.)  For the convex case it's probably a global maximum. To probabilistically improve the result for non-convex cases (like your example), you'd randomize the starting position, dropping the polygon many times, taking the best result. Note you don't really need a full blown physics engine (though [they certainly exist in open source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-physicsengines/index.html)). It's enough to use collision resolution to tell you how to rotate and translate the rectangle in a pseudo-physical way as it twists and slides uniformly down the z axis as far as possible.
2. Different physics model.  Suppose the black area is an attractive field generator in 2d following the usual inverse square rule like gravity and magnetism.  Now let the rectangle drift in a damping medium responding to this field.  It ought to settle with a maximal area overlapping the black area. There are problems with "nulls" like at the center of a donut, but I don't think these can ever be stable equillibria.  Can they? The simulation could be easily done by modeling both shapes as particle swarms.  Or since the rectangle is a simple shape and you are a physicist, you could come up with a closed form for the integral of attractive force between a point and the rectangle.  This way only the black shape needs representation as particles.  Come to think of it, if you can come up with a closed form for torque and linear attraction due to two triangles, then you can decompose both shapes with a (e.g. Delaunay) triangulation and get a *precise* answer.  Unfortunately [this discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23181/gravitational-attraction-of-triangles) implies it can't be done analytically.  So particle clouds may be the final solution.  The good news is that modern processors, particularly GPUs, do very large particle computations with amazing speed. **Edit:** I implemented this quick and dirty. It works great for convex shapes, but concavities create stable points that aren't what you want. Using the example: [image: Here's a screen shot]
3. This problem is related to [robot path planning](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node261.html).  Looking at this literature may turn up some ideas  In RPP you have obstacles and a robot and want to find a path the robot can travel while avoiding and/or sliding along them.  If the robot is asymmetric and can rotate, then  2d planning is done in a 3d (toroidal) configuration space (C-space) where one dimension is rotation (so closes on itself).  The idea is to "grow" the obstacles in C-space while shrinking the robot to a point.  Growing the obstacles is achieved by computing Minkowski Differences.) If you decompose all polygons to convex shapes, then there is a simple "edge merge" algorithm for computing the MD.)  When the C-space representation is complete, any 1d path that does not pierce the "grown" obstacles corresponds to continuous translation/rotation of the robot in world space that avoids the original obstacles.  For your problem the *white* area is the obstacle and the rectangle is the robot.  You're looking for any open point at all. This would correspond to 100% coverage.  For the less than 100% case, the C-space would have to be a function on 3d that reflects how "bad" the intersection of the robot is with the obstacle rather than just a binary value.  You're looking for the least bad point.  C-space representation is an open research topic.  An octree might work here.

Lots of details to think through in both cases, and they may not pan out at all, but at least these are frameworks to think more about the problem. The physics idea is a bit like using simulated spring systems to do graph layout, which has been very successful.

Comment: These are fantastic ideas! I really appreciate your lateral thought on these. Sadly your first idea is broken by a general case where the shape has a large number of internal gaps (imagine [this shape](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvOuf.png), where the optimum position is not an internal shape). I'm going to have to sit down and work through your second reply (I completed a physics degree rather than a computer science one, so I missed out on path planning concepts!) but that one looks promising!

Comment: Great. I still think a physical model has hope.  See new idea # 2 above.

Comment: That new answer looks very interesting! There would need to be some optimisations, but point-to-point attractor calculation could, as you say, probably find an exact answer! I'll eave the question about for a while just in case there are any more ideas but that looks like a winner! Thanks :)

Comment: Please see edit in post.  I tried the "force field" idea with some success but far from total.  Can provide code if of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to find the *precise* maximum for this problem, so you will need to make do with an approximation.

You could potentially render the vector image into a bitmap and use Haar features for this - they provide a very quick O(1) way of calculating the average colour of a rectangular region.

You'd still need to perform this multiple times for different rotations and positions, but it would bring it algorithmic complexity down from a naive O(n^5) to O(n^3) which may be acceptably fast. (with n here being the size of the different degrees of freedom you are scanning)

Comment: An excellent suggestion - I wasn't aware of Haar averaging. As you say, it'd still be a large number of checks, but it'd be significantly smaller!

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought to keep track of the remaining white space inside the blocks with something like if whitespace !== 0?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow what you mean!

Comment: Well, if you're looking for the amount of black-space coverage, then you will be looking at a very large number.  If you look for whether or not any white space exists, then you're only looking at 1's and 0's.

Comment: Oh I understand. Sadly you still have to look at each pixel, so checking whether it's black or white won't increase the speed I'm afraid!

Comment: Actually, that isn't true.  I can think of a number of different ways that you can avoid looking at each pixel.  For example, you might only look at the pixels along the edges of the white within the shape.  More efficiently, the pixels on the edges of the black contained within the shape.  Even better, only 1 picture on the edge of the black contained within the shape.

Comment: Wouldn't those methods prevent me from detecting enclosed white within a black shape?

Comment: @JP. Just the opposite.  They would verify whether or not the black shape were completely within the white.  The maximization problem is a whole 'nother animal.